# Matlab : 256 binary matrices to one 256 levels grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, grayscale

a process of mine produces 256 binary (logical) matrices, one for each level of a grayscale source image.

Here is the code :

```
so = imread('bio_sd.bmp');
co = rgb2gray(so);

for l = 1:256
    bw = (co == l); %         Binary image from level l of original image
    be = ordfilt2(bw, 1, ones(3, 3)); %  Convolution filter
    bl(int16(l)) = {bwlabel(be, 8)}; %   Component labelling
end
```

I obtain a cell array of 256 binary images. Such a binary image contains 1s if the source-image pixel at that location has the same level as the index of the binary image.

ie. the binary image bl{12} contains 1s where the source image has pixels with the level 12.

I'd like to create new image by combining the 256 binary matrices back to a grayscale image.

But i'm very new to Matlab and i wonder if someone can help me to code it :)

ps : i'm using matlab R2010a student edition.

Comment: Can you be sure that there's exactly one "1" and 255 "0" for every pixel? If not, how should the conflict be resolved?

Comment: No, there is one level value for each pixel of the source image. A binary image contains 1s if the source-image pixel at that location has the same level as the index of the binary image.

Comment: Seeing the code you added in your edit of the question: I think you should look very closely at what your code actually does, in contrast to what you think it does, and at the documentation for the functions you use. For example, bwlabel can easily return values larger than one, in contrast to what you seem to think. I don't think the current code is close to what you want it to do...

Comment: Sorry, it seems that i cannot make my question clear enough.

Comment: @gnovice gave a great explanation what your code does. Note that there also is an off-by-one error in the loop variable of your original code: grey values will go from 0 to 255 so the loop variable `l` should not go up to 256, and should probably start at 0 instead of 1. Of course this means you can't use `l` as an index into `bl` directly, you need to use `l+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What your code does...

I thought it may be best to first go through what the code you posted is actually doing, since there are a couple of inconsistencies. I'll go through each line in your loop:

- `bw = (co == l);`

  This simply creates a binary matrix `bw` with ones where your grayscale image `co` has a pixel intensity equal to the loop value `l`. I notice that you loop from 1 to 256, and this strikes me as odd. Typically, [images loaded into MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html) will be an [unsigned 8-bit integer type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uint8.html), meaning that the grayscale values will span the range 0 to 255. In such a case, the last binary matrix `bw` that you compute when `l = 256` will always contain all zeroes. Also, you don't do any processing for pixels with a grayscale level of 0. From your subsequent processing, I'm guessing you purposefully want to ignore grayscale values of 0, in which case you probably only need to loop from 1 to 255.
- `be = ordfilt2(bw, 1, ones(3, 3));`

  What you are essentially doing here with [ORDFILT2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) is performing a [binary erosion operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imerode.html). Any values of 1 in `bw` that have a 0 as one of their 8 neighbors will be set to 0, causing islands of ones to erode (i.e. shrink in size). Small islands of ones will disappear, leaving only the larger clusters of contiguous pixels with the same grayscale level.
- `bl(int16(l)) = {bwlabel(be, 8)};`

  Here's where you may be having some misunderstandings. Firstly, the matrices in `bl` **are not** [logical matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html). In your example, the function [BWLABEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwlabel.html) will find clusters of 8-connected ones. The first cluster found will have its elements labeled as 1 in the output image, the second cluster found will have its elements labeled as 2, etc. The matrices will therefore contain positive integer values, with 0 representing the background.

  Secondly, are you going to use these labeled clusters for anything? There may be further processing you do for which you need to identify separate clusters at a given grayscale intensity level, but with regard to creating a grayscale image from the elements in `bl`, the specific label *value* is unnecessary. You only need to identify zero versus non-zero values, so if you aren't using `bl` for anything else I would suggest that you just save the individual values of `be` in a cell array and use them to recreate a grayscale image.

### Now, onto the answer...

A very simple solution is to concatenate your cell array of images into a 3-D matrix using the function [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html), then use the function [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) to find the indices where the non-zero values occur along the third dimension (which corresponds to the grayscale value from the original image). For a given pixel, if there is no non-zero value found along the third dimension (i.e. it is all zeroes) then we can assume the pixel value should be 0. However, the index for that pixel returned by [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) will default to 1, so you have to use the maximum value as a logical index to set the pixel to 0:

```
[maxValue,grayImage] = max(cat(3,bl{:}),[],3);
grayImage(~maxValue) = 0;
```

Note that for the purposes of [displaying](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) or [saving](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) the image you may want to change the type of the resulting image `grayImage` to an unsigned 8-bit integer type, like so:

```
grayImage = uint8(grayImage);
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete and real answer, and the time you've consacred to my problem. I'm aware that the code i posted is incomplete / buggy, but it was a first draft, and i posted it hoping it will be clearer to understand my problem. I had the intuition that Matlab could be well adapted to this problem. I ended coding it with OpenCV in C, it works but the code is considerably longer :)

Answer (score 3):

*this whole answer only applies to the [original form of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6226391/1).*

Lets assume you can get all your binary matrices together into a big n-by-m-by-256 matrix `binaryimage(x,y,greyvalue)`. Then you can calculate your final image as

```
newimage=sum(bsxfun(@times,binaryimage,reshape(0:255,1,1,[])),3)
```

The magic here is done by bsxfun, which multiplies the 3D (n x m x 256) binaryimage with the 1 x 1 x 256 vector containing the grey values 0...255. This produces a 3D image where for fixed x and y, the vector (y,x,:) contains many zeros and (for the one grey value `G` where the binary image contained a `1`) it contains the value `G`. So now you only need to sum over this third dimension to get a `n x m` image.

**Update**

To test that this works correctly, lets go the other way first:

```
fullimage=floor(rand(100,200)*256);
figure;imshow(fullimage,[0 255]);
```

is a random greyscale image. You can calculate the 256 binary matrices like this:

```
binaryimage=false([size(fullimage) 256]);
for i=1:size(fullimage,1)
   for j=1:size(fullimage,2)
      binaryimage(i,j,fullimage(i,j)+1)=true;
   end
end
```

We can now apply the solution I gave above

```
newimage=sum(bsxfun(@times,binaryimage,reshape(0:255,1,1,[])),3);
```

and verify that I returns the original image:

```
all(newimage(:)==fullimage(:))
```

which gives `1` (true) :-).

**Update 2**

You now mention that your binary images are in a cell array, I assume `binimg{1:256}`, with each cell containing an n x m binary array. If you can it probably makes sense to change the code that produces this data to create the 3D binary array I use above - cells are mostly usefull if different cells contain data of different types, shapes or sizes.

If there are good reasons to stick with a cell array, you can convert it to a 3D array using

```
binaryimage = reshape(cell2mat(reshape(binimg,1,256)),n,m,256);
```

with `n` and `m` as used above. The inner reshape is not necessary if you already have `size(binimg)==[1 256]`. So to sum it up, you need to use your cell array `binimg` to calculate the 3D matrix binaryimage, which you can then use to calculate the `newimage` that you are interested in using the code at the very beginning of my answer.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your (very quick) answers, i appreciate that. But i'm stuck with a comprehension problem. My binary images are n-by-m matrices of logical values (true/false). I have 256 of them, collected in a cell array. How can i multiply them with the grey level value ? I can't see that in your answer :/

Comment: I should add that the new image, combining all the levels from the binary images, is not the same that the original image, a group of filters is applied.

Comment: Hi @Laurent, if you have additional information it also makes sense to add it to your question, so it is more visible for others. I added an update to my answer to deal with cell arrays. I'm not sure about your second comment: in your question you only ask about going from binary image to a normal image (which I have called newimage in my code samples). At what point do you need to add filters in this process??

Comment: Hi @Jonas, i updated the question to clarify. The filters are applied to each level of the 256 levels source image, and produce 256 binary images, on for each level, which i'd like to recombine into a resulting grayscale image.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to iterate through each of your logical matrices in turn, multiply it by its corresponding weight, and accumulate into an output matrix which will represent your final image.